# Need to hash up to 500 char string (think password style encryption), that would be difficult to reverse

Tags: php, string, encryption, hash

I am storing "secret" strings in a database as a hash (in case data is compromised).  I was using bcrypt, but found out that it apparently only takes the first 55 characters.  Basically someone will try to guess these secret strings, and I currently hash their guess and compare it to the hashed "secret" string.

What would be the best way to do this?  Bcrypt will not work since some strings will be up to 500 characters.  Any Ideas?

Comment: After some research I am thinking SHA1 or SHA256... I'll give these a try

Comment: are you using PHP? if  yes: then crypt can be used for more than 55 characters!

Comment: @Akam,
crypt($secret, $Blowfish_Pre . $salt . $Blowfish_End)
seems to not care about anything beyond the 72nd character of $secret

Comment: This maybe an issue in the mCrypt PHP module. Try using [Crypt_Blowfish](http://pear.php.net/package/Crypt_Blowfish) - it does not use mCrypt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't just use a plain hash(be it MD5, SHA-1 or SHA-2) if inputs are guessable. Validating a guess is cheap with them.

A simple trick is to first hash the input with SHA-256 (cutting it down to 32 bytes or 43 Base64 chars) and then apply bcrypt to that.

That way bcrypt takes care of being expensive and salted, and SHA-256 takes care of large inputs.

See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30315/fixing-the-high-bit-problem-in-phps-crypt-implementation/30326#30326

Comment: OOOHHHH, And I would have to change very little code to do this :) .  You Rock!!  Basically just add sha1() inside of the bcrypt function I already use :)

Comment: @Eddie I'd prefer SHA-2 over SHA-1, even if might not matter in practice for your application.

Comment: is that because SHA-2 has less collisions? these will typically be 250-500 character "secrets".

Comment: @Eddie In first order it's PR. Currently if you use MD5 people will scream at you, no matter if it's actually a problem, and SHA1 will reach that status soon. SHA-256 is stronger, and there are no downsides to using it. | In your case using SHA-1 probably won't break your system.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Blowfish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_%28cipher%29) - symmetric encryption algorithm without length limitations.

PHP Pear has implementation for [Crypt_Blowfish](http://pear.php.net/package/Crypt_Blowfish) class.

If ability to decrypt is not necessary, it would be better to use something like `SHA1`. PHP also [has support for it](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php).

Comment: Interesting as I am using blowfish, and it appears that anything after  the 72nd character is just ignored... but Yes I will try an SHA1 or SHA256 encryption.  From what I understand, SHA256 is a newer hashing algorithm and reduced collisions (which likely wont be a problem with either)

Comment: I did not have any problems with `blowfish` and size limits, but I simply used `openssl bf` to encrypt/decrypt it. Regarding sha: I would not bother with sha256, `sha1` is way to go - nobody was able to create a single collision yet. And it is used very widely, for example in `git`. But, be sure to salt it - don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Sounds good...I'll stick with sha1.  I already have a salt col in my db so that shouldn't be a problem.  I plan on giving each "secret" its own salt.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a huge fan of MD5, it's faster than SHA and it's virtually un-reversible. I have used it to do entire files as a checksum comparison. Besides it's a built in function in PHP.

Simply MD5 the incoming string and compair it to the MD5ed answer stored in the database.

The MD5 string is only 32 characters long. While it his wonderful for keeping database size down, there is a possibility that two long string will actually have the same MD5 result, but this is highly improbable.

Comment: Interesting.  I was under the impression that MD5 was easier to reverse... maybe that is only on short strings?

Comment: The problem is that MD5 is fast, and thus verifying guesses is cheap. You could use it in PBKDF2 with sufficient iterations, but that'd still be inferior to bcrypt.